# Google play Console, Сбой при загрузке

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, manifest

Не удается загрузить в консоли разработчика Google play файл apk или aab своей игры.
При загрузке всегда выдает текст:

Сбой при загрузке

Манифест загруженного APK-файла или набора Android App Bundle указывает на документ с набором атрибутов действий, однако подобные документы пока не разрешены. Если вы участвуете в программе бета-тестирования, попросите занести свой аккаунт разработчика в белый список.

[image: Фото ошибки]
Уже весь интернет перелазил и ответа на такую ошибку нигде не нашел.
Файл манифеста на мой взгляд ничем не отличается от гайдов

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="gorbachew.pythonanywhere.ru"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.0"

    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".AuthorsActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".AuthorsActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/achborderoff" />
        <activity android:name=".Start">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Start" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Game">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Game" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Проблема в блоке <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.actions" Похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202330/google-play-does-not-accept-my-actions-schema)

Comment: Думаю, вам это пригодится - [https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/reference/actionsxml](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/reference/actionsxml)
Здесь описание actions.xml

Comment: @SindeGrave Благодарю! Удалил этот блок и билд загрузился. Голову сломал, где может быть проблема в сборке